# Why is realloc only copying part of the data?

Tags: c, memory, realloc

So I ran into an issue where it seemed like realloc wasn't copying all of the data in a buffer so I decided to run the following code as a test.

```
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    int* tmp_array = malloc(sizeof(int) * 2);
    tmp_array[0] = 1;
    tmp_array[1] = 2;
    tmp_array = realloc(tmp_array, 4);

    return 0;
}
```

The same issue I originally had was still happening, only part of the data is being copied. The 1 in the buffer gets copied, however the 2 does not. I am allocating enough space for 2 integers at first so both if the assignments to tmp_array should be valid. Then reallocating to 4 seems valid. I even tried explicitly casting the returned realloc pointer to int* but that didn't help.

Unfortunately, I can't show the screenshots of my memory window in the debugger (VS 2017) but it definitely shows the 1 and 2 in the buffer before realloc and only shows the 1 in the buffer after the realloc.

I'm sure I could reimplement realloc myself by just using malloc and memcpy to copy the data over manually, but I still just want to know why this isn't working.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 6):

You are reallocating to `4` bytes, not to `4*sizeof(int)`, which incidentally copies just first `int` (and discards other).

`realloc`, as `malloc`, works on bytes so you must use them both in the same way.